# prove this equation in continuum mechanics

Tags: calculus

Hello I have a question from continuum mechanics,
If the three functions u, v, and w of x1, x2, and x3 satisfy F(u, v,w) = 0
show that 
∇u · ∇v × ∇w = 0

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The last means that the gradients are linearly dependent. So you should show that the first relation implies this linear dependency (which is btw true only at a regular point of $F$).

Comment: thx I don't konw how to use F(u,v,w) = 0 for solving